# Using local images without creating a local registry in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am fairly new to docker and kubernetes and going through kubernetes [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#use-local-images-by-re-using-the-docker-daemon) it says,

> When using a single VM for Kubernetes, it’s useful to reuse Minikube’s built-in Docker daemon. Reusing the built-in daemon means you don’t have to build a Docker registry on your host machine and push the image into it. Instead, you can build inside the same Docker daemon as Minikube, which speeds up local experiments.

So, my understanding is there are two instances are running in my local machine, one in macOS and the other one in the VM.

Suppose I created a image using the docker instance on my macOS, and then I want to use it on Kubernetes then,

**Question 1:** Do I strictly need to create a local registry and then pull it from within Kubernetes cluster ?

It further says,

> To work with the Docker daemon on your Mac/Linux host, use the docker-env command in your shell: `eval $(minikube docker-env)`

Running this creates a few environment variables in the current shell.

**Question 2:** Will this be able to pull images that I build from within the docker in my macOS without creating the local registry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minikube runs a single-node Kubernetes cluster inside a Virtual Machine (VM) on your laptop.
So it will create a k8s setup on a VM running on your macOS.

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

this command on you macOS will help you to switch context to docker,  so that you can run docker commands from your macOS.

**Question 1: Do I strictly need to create a local registry and then pull it from within Kubernetes cluster ?** 
No you don't need to explicitly create a local registry as everthing runs on a single VM in minikube.

**Question 2: Will this be able to pull images that I build from within the docker in my macOS without creating the local registry?** 
By switching docker env context on your host machine you can able to pull the images you don't need create a registry for that. Remember your macOS is not the part of you k8s cluster. Your k8s cluster is running on the single VM created by minikube.